# Issue creating a User through an Account model Rails 5 with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What I'm trying to accomplish:

When a user registers with my app they are taken to a new account creation page. This is where they enter their desired subdomain. from this form I also want to create the owner (a user class).

The problem:

As it sits right now, when i fill out the generated form (below)

```
<%= form_for @account do |f| %>

<%= fields_for :owner do |o| %>
  <p>
  <%= o.label :f_name %>
  <%= o.text_field :f_name %>
</p>
  <p>
  <%= o.label :m_name %>
  <%= o.text_field :m_name %>
</p>
  <p>
  <%= o.label :l_name %>
  <%= o.text_field :l_name %>
</p>
  <p>
  <%= o.label :email %>
  <%= o.email_field :email %>
</p>
  <p>
  <%= o.label :password %>
  <%= o.password_field :password %>
</p>
  <p>
  <%= o.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= o.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</p>

<% end %>

<p>
  <%= f.label :subdomain %>
  <%= f.text_field :subdomain %>
</p>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and try to submit the form, I get the following rails server output:

```
Started POST "/accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-08 21:52:57 -0600
Processing by AccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4yUhk6N40udNBMoBJz/sFzbjC/RUtU7FVyHe9NlhtBkmpGEMZE0+xMcD7E6GLOjgp02hbkrbuMNLQ5gBjh+kvA==", "owner"=>{"f_name"=>"xxxxx", "m_name"=>"xxxxx", "l_name"=>"xxxxx", "email"=>"xxxxx@xxxxxnltd.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "account"=>{"subdomain"=>"testinga"}, "commit"=>"Create Account"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Account Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "accounts" WHERE LOWER("accounts"."subdomain") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["subdomain", "testinga"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Rendering accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 49ms (Views: 21.5ms | ActiveRecord: 8.3ms)
```

Now when I read the output I cant seem to find why this is rolling back and not saving. I do see it telling me an account already exists whit that subdomain, however this is a CLEAN database and there are no accounts saved in it! When I run `byebug` just before the @account.save in the accounts controller (below) there are no error messages or details I can find.

My `AccountController`: (I've left the byebug in the controller, perhaps im putting it in the wrong place?)

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    @account.build_owner
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    byebug
    if @account.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Account creates successfully.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

private

  def account_params
    params.require(:account).permit(:subdomain, :owner_id, :plan_id, :account_verified, :account_status, owner_attributes: [:id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :f_name, :m_name, :l_name, :office_country_code, :office_phone_number, :mobile_country_code, :mobile_phone_number])
  end

end
```

My `Account` model

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord

  RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS = %w(www admin loadlead)

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :users

  validates :owner, presence: true
  validates :subdomain, presence: true,
            #uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
            format: { with: /\A[\w\-]+\Z/i, message: 'contains invalid characters'},
            exclusion: { in: RESTRICTED_SUBDOMAINS, message: 'restricted name'}

  before_validation :downcase_subdomain

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :owner

protected

  def downcase_subdomain
    self.subdomain = subdomain.try(:downcase)
  end

end
```

My `User` model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  belongs_to :account

end
```

Any assistance here would be greatly appreciated! I have no idea where I'm going wrong with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, Where do `:owner_id, :plan_id, :account_verified, :account_status` come from? I didn't see them in your code.

Comment: owner_id should be generated when the owner is created on form submit. :account_verified will come at a later stage in the account setup process as will account_status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `fields_for` on `f` builder instead:

```
<%= form_for @account do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :owner do |o| %>
    <p>
      <%= o.label :f_name %>
      <%= o.text_field :f_name %>
    </p>

    # ....
  <% end %>

  # ....
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

And you can remove `:owner_id`, this attribute value will be set automatically by `Rails` when we're using `:accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Comment: f.fields for fixed the problem! i also removed the owner_id as suggested! thanks!!!!!

Comment: Its not really set automatically by rails - the id is created by the database when you insert the row.

Comment: Hi @max, Yes, the id is created by the database, then Rails will associate `owners.id` to `accounts.owner_id` before saving `accounts` to the database, right?

Comment: Yes, the parent record in the association is always inserted first.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `@account.save` which does not raise an exception. It returns `true` if everything is fine, or returns `false` when the validation fails (if `@account.valid?` returns `false`).

If there are any validation errors, you can check them by calling:

```
pry(main)> @account.valid?
pry(main)> false
pry(main)> @account.errors
```

That should help you debug the issue.